# Running external program from PowerShell slows it down

Tags: powershell, imagemagick, mogrify

I'm trying to resize large images in folder with **mogrify**:

`mogrify -resize "10000x900>" *.jpg`

If run on cmd (Windows 10), it goes almost instantly on folder with 50 pictures. However, I need a script to first check if the image is big enough, and then selectively resize only larger images.

This PowerShell script works fine, however, it takes around 1-2 seconds for each individual image. Why is that so, and how to speed things up?

```
$images = Get-ChildItem *.jpg
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
foreach ($img in $images) {
     $Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($img)
     $imageHeight = $Image.Height
     $Image.Dispose() 

     if ($imageHeight -gt 900) {
          & mogrify -resize "10000x900>" $img
     }
 }
```

Comment: A fairly simple optimization - assuming that `mogrify` accepts an open-ended number of individual filename arguments - is to build up the list of files to resize first, and then pass them to a single invocation of `mogrify`.

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm more interested in what is wrong with invocation of command, where is the culprit of this lag. If I replace it with for example simple "dir" external command, it runs instantly. As said, Mogrify from cmd runs instantly as well, but when run from PowerShell, it slows down.

Comment: If the very same `mogrify` command by itself ran more slowly in PowerShell than in `cmd.exe`, that would be worth exploring - do you actually see that? Otherwise, your only option for speeding this up (aside from the optimization already suggested and aside from creating a dedicated program in a compiled language) is to ad-hoc compile C# code that performs the image-inspection loop with `Add-Type`. Speaking of the latter: `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing` is a simpler way to load the assembly.

Comment: P.S.: Almost instantaneous execution with 50 image files sounds suspiciously fast.